# Angular with Jquery - How to include jQuery into a factory and use / share that factory among multiple controllers?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-factory

I have a longer jQuery function for an image gallery slider. I have about 5 directives (all using he same slider with different pictures). As I didn't want to copy paste the same jQuery code into all 5 controllers, I did it using a factory.
I put the jQuery code into a factory, then called the factory in each controller. Its not working but I can't see why. Does anyone know?Thank you!
EDIT: Jquery is included bevor angular and works! The problem is not jQuery itself but the factory. If I use the same jQuery code over and over again in all controllers, its working. Its not working if i put it in the factory and can the factory in controllers.
Factory:

```
app.factory('prodsFactory', function ($http) {
  var prodsFactory = {};
    prodsFactory.slider=function(){
       $(function(){
           ...
        })
     }
 })
```

1st directive:

```
app.directive('picturesProject', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'projects/shop/picturesshop.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'shopCtrl',
        link: function(scope){
        }
 }

})

app.controller('shopCtrl', function($scope,prodsFactory){
        return prodsFactory.slider();
});
```

index.html
...

```
<script src="projects/shop/picturesshop.directive.js"></script>
```

...

Comment: Controllers constructin functions don't use returned values, so what do you expect to happen when the code invokes a factory function and returns that value to a controller construction function?

Comment: if I don't return but just call it, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: well by doesn't work, i mean that anything insight the jQuery function is not being executed. It only works if I put the jQuery code again and again into each of the 5 controllers- not when I put it into the factory and call it from the controllers.

Comment: Put some `console.log` statements in the code. I think you will find that the jQuery function **is** being executed, but not when you expect. In directives, the controller is constructed **before** the postLink function is invoked.

Comment: I put a few console.logs and absolutely nothing coms up, meaning the entire function is just not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

If the jQuery library script is included before the AngularJS library script, jQuery is made available as `angular.element`.

> If jQuery is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or **jqLite.**
>
> To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file. You can also use the `ngJq` directive to specify that jqlite should be used over jQuery, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple versions exist on the page.
>
> [-- AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

That said, the factory needs to return something to its construction function:

```
app.factory('prodsFactory', function ($http) {
  var $ = angular.element;
  var prodsFactory = {};
    prodsFactory.slider=function(){
      $(function(){
          console.log("jQuery prodsFactory slider invoked");
      });
    };
  //RETURN prodsFactory to construction function
  //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  return prodsFactory;
 });
```

Comment: the problem is not jQuery but the factory. thats what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery before your angularjs scripts if you plan to utilise any jquery functions that are not implement in angular's jquery lite implementation.

Comment: i did. jQuery works itself. the only thing that doesn't work is if i put it into a factory and then try calling the factory in controllers.

Comment: In your factory, have you tried placing a 'return prodsFactory' ?